# Filter on Foreign Key with LATERAL JOIN brings yields strange results

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, lateral-join

thanks for your time!

Basically, I'm trying to filter a NxM table using foreign keys, with 0,1 or N different tags. The problem is that LEFT LATERAL JOIN yields bizarre results.
Please, don't mind the strange casting, I'm doing so because I'm using spring boot.
Here is a fiddle showing a fake relationship:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6bDu33keWACHssLqznk88n/0

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE posts (id int primary key);
CREATE TABLE tags (id int primary key);
CREATE TABLE post_tags (post_id int references posts(id),
                        tags_id int references tags(id),
                       primary key (post_id, tags_id));

INSERT INTO posts VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (8), (9);
INSERT INTO post_tags VALUES (1,8), (1,9), (2,8);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from posts p
left join lateral (select * from post_tags pt where pt.post_id = p.id) pt on 1=1
where (1 is null or pt.tags_id = any(cast(STRING_TO_ARRAY(CAST('9' AS TEXT), ',') AS INT[])));
```

| id | post_id | tags_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9 |

---

**Query #2**

```
select * from posts p
left join lateral (select * from post_tags pt where pt.post_id = p.id limit 1) pt on 1=1
where (1 is null or pt.tags_id = any(cast(STRING_TO_ARRAY(CAST('9' AS TEXT), ',') AS INT[])));
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #3**

```
select * from posts p
left join lateral (select * from post_tags pt where pt.post_id = p.id) pt on 1=1
where (1 is null or pt.tags_id = any(cast(STRING_TO_ARRAY(CAST('9,8' AS TEXT), ',') AS INT[])));
```

| id | post_id | tags_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 |

---

**Query #4**

```
select * from posts p
left join lateral (select * from post_tags pt where pt.post_id = p.id limit 1) pt on 1=1
where (1 is null or pt.tags_id = any(cast(STRING_TO_ARRAY(CAST('9,8' AS TEXT), ',') AS INT[])));
```

| id | post_id | tags_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6bDu33keWACHssLqznk88n/0)

If you notice, query #2 yields no results, although it should. I suspect the `limit 1` is not allowing it to function properly. But if I remove it, I get duplicate results (as seen in query #3).

My question is, how can I filter on foreign keys and not having duplicate results?

EDIT ---

I expect the query to return at most 1 result per category that matches the where clause;
Query #2 should return:

| id | post_id | tags_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9 |

Or in case multi tags are passed, it should return just like query #4 (both matches, post 1 and 2, but not duplicated posts (post id = 1)

Thanks

Comment: Which result do you actually *want*?

Comment: I'll edit with the expected result! Sorry and thanks for pointing it

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is a problem with the `where` clause. It is filtering on `pt.tag_id`, but that column comes from the left join, so it may be `null`. So when a post has no tags it is always filtered out.

It also occurs to me that you don’t really need a join (which may cause cardinality issues as you are seeing) ; if you just want to filter the posts per tag, `exists` seems more appropriate:

```
select p.*
from post p
where exists (
    select 1
    from post_tag pt
    where pt_post_id = p.id
      and pt.tags_id = any(cast(STRING_TO_ARRAY(CAST('9,8' AS TEXT), ',') AS INT[]))
)
```

Comment: Not sure if that's what I'm looking for. Doing so will also return post_id = 1 and tags_id = 8, which I don't want in this case. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Leonardo: this generates one row per post that has (at least) one matching tag. Isn’t this what you want?